# Good resources for learning how to build a solid logging/debuging infrastructure for .Net MVC web sites/apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, logging

I was wondering if someone could point me towards some good resources for learning how to build a solid logging/(remote) debugging infrastructure for .Net MVC web sites/apps to gather info for when things go bad.  I know SO was built using .Net MVC and I wish I could pick Atwoods brain for even an hour because I bet he had some incredible analysis code/tools in place for troubleshooting bugs.  Are there any community wikis surrounding this topic?  Other tuts/sites?

I'm going to begin researching this topic right now, but I thought'd I post this question in the meantime and get anyone's thoughts just to give me a boost.  Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jeff blogged about using ELMAH - http://code.google.com/p/elmah/.